# How do I recursively create a folder inside another non-existent folder?

Tags: command-line

I want to create this folder: `$HOME/a/b/c/d` while `$HOME/a` has not yet been created! Is it possible with one line in Terminal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the command `mkdir` with `-p` option to create a folder inside another non-existent folder. Consider an example,

```bsh
mkdir -p "$HOME/a/b/c/d"
```

Where the folders `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` do not exist in home before running the command. After execution of the command all these folders will be created recursively inside one another.

You can see from [`man mkdir`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/mkdir.1.html)

```
-p, --parents
          no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to the question,below command will do the job you want in just the way you want :) This can be done with mkdir (make directory command) as shown below:

```
root@test:~# sudo mkdir -p /abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop/qrst/uvwx/yz/  
root@test:~#
```

If you want it to show you the directories it created while it is working then use verbose with it as shown below:

```
root@test:~# sudo mkdir -pv /abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop/qrst/uvwx/yz/  
mkdir: created directory `/abcd'
mkdir: created directory `/abcd/efgh'  
mkdir: created directory `/abcd/efgh/ijkl'  
mkdir: created directory `/abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop'  
mkdir: created directory `/abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop/qrst'  
mkdir: created directory `/abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop/qrst/uvwx'  
mkdir: created directory `/abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop/qrst/uvwx/yz/'  
root@test:~#
```

Enjoy!! :)